# Async threads reading from a single source, round-robin style, and writing to a single target, in order

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, f#

I have a multi-line file where each line is of the format *n - Some text*, where *n* is a running index.

I want to go over the lines of the file such that each thread I spawn takes the *n + 1* line until file's end is reached, in a round-robin.

Furthermore, I like each thread that read a line matching a predicate (say *n % 2 = 0*, assume I know how to do the predicate matching) to write the line to another single file, but I also want those matching threads to write in the correct order (So, target file contains lines 2, 4, etc. in that order).

Using `File.ReadLines` reads all lines at once, so is not what I'm looking for. `File.AsyncReadLines` still reads all lines.

Lastly, is there any way I can limit the thread pool's size, arbitrarily?

Comment: You have two conflicting requirements here: "Each thread takes the *n + 1* line until file's end ... in a round-robin" and "Threads should read the file in parallel" cannot both be true. Once you kick off a set of worker threads in parallel, you have **no control** over which one gets scheduled next. You could reassert some control by using some sort of lock, but then you would lose all benefit of parallelism. I feel like this is an XY problem, where you need to do Y and you think the only way to do it is X. What is the problem you're trying to solve with this? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Oh yeah... It didn't occur to me, but, of course, you're right. There is no _problem_ per-se, I want to learn how to use `async` and so I want, I'll restate my question in light of your comment, to spawn a couple of threads, *do* have those take _n_ + 1 line until end of file, compare to a predict and write, all to the same file, in order, those lines that passed the predicate. I'll restate the actual question as well. As usual... thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're just wanting to learn `async` by reading code that other people have written for you, I'd recommend reading https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/ for that. If you want to learn by *doing*, then it's better to write your own code and see what it does than to read code that other people have written for you.